# Resizing images, save bandwidth and file count in my shared hosting

Tags: php, shared-hosting, image-resizing

I am using shared web hosting which provides only limited options for the package I choosed. I can have only 10,000 files in my account and the 5 GB of bandwidth. This policy has been implemented and they are forcing me to cleanup the files or they will block my account or I need to upgrade my account. When I signed up, they offered me unlimited file count and unlimited bandwidth. I have been using it for more than a year now. I do not want to upgrade my account and do not want to move to some other hosting at this point of time.

I have around 75000 image files in my website and am using around 25 gb bandwidth per month approx. Out of these 75000 image files, 3750 are unique images. rest of them are the same image with different sizes. I mean I have an image file with 19 different sizes. each file has a unique name. For example,

one of the unique image has file name as ab171.png
the same image with size 800x600 will have file name as ab171_800_600.jpg
the same image with size 640x480 will have file name as ab171_640_480.jpg
similarly i have other files

so, each image file set has 1 main file and 19 other files with different image sizes.

Images from my site are used on around 20+ sites. around 10 are authorized to use and the rest are not. I would like to block the sites which are not in my list or warn them not use my bandwidth. I wouldn't mind them using my images if I can accomplish the below idea.

Now, to resolve my file count and bandwidth issue, I got an idea that I can host the main file to a image hosting site and resize it using timthumb script on the fly. (I have a paid image hosting account which I can use it.)

Here is what I have done so far:

a. I have extracted the exact image file name (ex filename: ab171_800_600)

b. redirected old file name to my script with the image file name as parameter (extracted in above step) Ex:
old url: myurl.com/images/thummbs/a/ab171_800_600.jpg
redirected as: myurl.com/thumbs.php?id=ab171_800_600

c. I wrote a php script thumbs.php which reads the query string id and extracts the image id, image width and image height. Then it checks the image id in database to get the image url (which is hosted in image hosting site).

d. then the scripts redirects to the timthumb.php with the image url (which is hosted in image hosting site), height and width as parameters.

So far, the above script works fine. If I navigate to my old url myurl.com/images/thummbs/a/ab171_800_600.jpg from browser, it perfectly fetches the image from image hosting and resizes it and shows in browser.

My problem is the image is not showing up in my/other sites where the old image urls are linked inside image tags. ex: <img src="http://myurl.com/images/thummbs/a/ab171_800_600.jpg" />

Please help on fixing this problem. Your suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to use the GD library instead. Just keep all the original images. When you need to display a thumbnail then let a php script generate the thumb for you. So an img tag could look like this: <img src="cropimg.php?w=100&h=100" />  -- The GD library is perfect this. And you're not stuck with all the other extra files with different dimensions.

Comment: Thanks. However, image url cannot be changed. I do not have control on most of the sites where my images are linked.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution will be **quit that swindling hoster ASAP.**

There are NO DOUBTS that they have added **CPU usage limits** as well as such a ridiculous files number limit.

The only result you will get from all your struggle is another limit breakage.
The only solution is to find another hosting, a sane one.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hmmm. frankly speaking, I do not have money to upgrade or switch hosting at this point of time. I have paid for this hosting for 2 years and have 1 year left. I hope to earn before that and switch the hosting soon. but not possible now. I do not earn anything from these images. I have earned in the past and needs to maintain the images as long as possible. Previously I was using free image hosting and they removed my images after some point of time. So, I hosted the images on my own site. Thanks

Comment: You didn't get the point. It is not on your own will. **they will block your account** for the excessive CPU usage and you will have to find another hosting anyway.

Comment: +1 - your host is screwing you. You can get shared hosting with unlimited bandwidth and disk space for ~$100 a year these days in MANY places.

Answer (score 0):

You need to avoid the redirect.

When you send a redirect back for a page, the browser will redirect the whole page to the location in the HTTP headers.

If you send a redirect back for an image, this cannot be done.

You need to design a solution that doesn't rely on a HTTP redirect. My recommendation would normally be to either:

1. Ask your users to update their links (not very practical)
2. Instead of redirecting, load the remote page inside of your PHP page so no redirect is required. You will need to set the correct content-type on the response

This second option will potentially put you back in the bandwidth problem zone, but you could help this a bit by giving the response a very long cache time.

Also, don't be afraid to find another hosting company if you are not getting the service you want.

Update - PHP Show Remote Image

You should only use this if you have permission from the people hosting the image. You should also be aware that because the image is displayed in your PHP page, it will use your bandwidth.

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg\n\n"); 
$ch = curl_init ("http://....image.jpg"); // The URL you have already calculated in your question
curl_setopt($ch, CurlOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CurlOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CurlOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$rawdata=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $rawdata;
```

Comment: Thanks. However, the first option is not suitable for me, as I cannot edit every location where the images are used. Can you explain me more on 2nd option, as I am still beginner in php.

Comment: I have added an example using CURL.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend either using file_get_contents() http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php or curl https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php to fetch the image depending on what your webhost allows.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I do not have problem on fetching the image from image hosting site.